# Why different array dereferencing in printf gives the same output?

Tags: c, arrays, pointers

Why do all the three print statements give the same output?

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void) {
    int arr[]={1,2,3,4,5};
    printf("%d\n",arr);
    printf("%d\n",&arr);
    printf("%d\n",*(&arr));
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Undefined behavior. In the first and third example your printing an `int *` but you are saying you are printing an int. in the second example your printing an `int *[5]` you should turn on compiler warnings and it will tell you this. Using gcc add `-Wall -Wextra` to your compiler options

Comment: In all three cases, you will see the memory address of your first array-element.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, you're "lucky" that all three are printing the same thing because you're using the wrong format specifier to `printf`.  You should be using `%p` to print a pointer.  Using the wrong format specifier invokes [undefined behavior](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior).

That being said, all three pointers you're printing have the same value.

In the first statement, you're passing in an array.  When passing an array to a function, it decays into a pointer to the first element.

For the second statement, you're taking the address of the array.  The address of an array is the same as the address of the first element, so this prints the same value as the first statement.

The third statement first takes the address of the array, yielding a pointer of type `int (*)[5]`, i.e. a pointer to an array of 5 ints.  You then dereference this pointer, giving you an array.  Like the first statement, this array decays to a pointer to the first element when passed to a function, so this value is the same as the first (as well as the second).